# How exactly do javascript numeric property names work?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this behavior?

```js
const obj = {};

obj[0] = 0;

console.log(obj['0']);  // 0

obj[0.1] = 0.1;

console.log(obj['0.1']);  // 0.1

obj[1.0] = 1.0;

console.log(obj['1.0']);  // undefined
```

It seems javascript converts the string integer numbers into an integer, but not exactly how it works in the calculation. Since string `'1.0'` should be the same as `1`.

Also is it possible to set 2 distinct attributes for one object of number `0` and string `"0"`? Can I avoid javascript convert the string into numbers while doing object lookup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript property names are *all* strings.

In this line:

```
obj[1.0] = 1.0;
```

`1.0` is first coerced to the string value `'1'`, and then `1.0` is assigned to `obj['1']`.

You can retrieve it the same way, if you pass in a number instead of the string value `1.0`. The same string conversion will be applied for property retrieval:

```js
const obj = {};

obj[1.0] = 1.0;

console.log(obj[1.0]);  // 1
```

However, the fact that the property names are strings is a little irrelevant here. Even if it had actual numeric property names, `1.0` would evaluate to the number `1` and the value would be assigned to `obj[1]` anyway.

> Also is it possible to set 2 distinct attributes for one object of number 0 and string "0"? Can I avoid javascript convert the string into numbers while doing object lookup?

No, `0` and `'0'` both evaluate to the property name `'0'`.

Comment: Wait, does that mean even the array indexes are all strings?

Comment: @HaoWu Yes. JS has some special treatment of indices that are integer values, but at the end of the day, they're all strings. `var a = [1,2,3]; console.log(a['1']); Object.keys(a);`

Comment: Wow, this is mind-blowing. I tried `a['NaN'] = 1` and then `a[0/0]` is actually equals to 1 as well...

Comment: @HaoWu One thing to note is that a `Map` allows storing key-value pairs with keys that can be of any type: `var m = new Map(); m.set(0, 1); m.set('0', 2); console.log(m.get(0), m.get('0'));`